# How to check if there is image title, caption, description?

Tags: attachments, images, captions, featured-post

I use this code to display featured image title, caption (excerpt), description (content):

`echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_title;
echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt;
echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_content;`

But, how to check if there is any of those fields first?

For example, how to check if there is caption, and if emty to show some other text?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more a programming question, but try this:

```
$post = get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
if ( !isset( $post->post_title ) ) {
    echo 'Sorry no title';
} else {
    echo $post->post_title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **if** statements.

```
if($caption = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt){
echo $caption;
}else{
//echo something else
}
```